# Exception handing in Spring Boot Rest API ResponseStatusException

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-restcontroller, spring-rest

> While running the program saying remove the catch clause.

```
@RestController @RequestMapping(value = "/api/")
public class EmployeeController {

private EmployeeService employeeService;

@Autowired
public EmployeeController(EmployeeService employeeService) {
    this.employeeService = employeeService;
}

@GetMapping(value = "employee")
public List<Employee> getAllEmployee() {
    try {
        return employeeService.findAllEmployees();
    } catch (MyResourceNotFoundException ex) {
        throw new ResponseStatusException(
          HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, "Employee not Found", ex);
    }
}
```

}

> This is the exception Class

```
@ResponseStatus(code = HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, reason = "Employee Not Found")
public class MyResourceNotFoundException extends Exception {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public MyResourceNotFoundException(String errorMessage) {
    super(errorMessage);
}
}
```

> Kindly find below screenshot. This is the exception which is being thrown while running the application.

[image]

Comment: Whether you throwing `MyResourceNotFoundException` in service layer?

Comment: You need to throw MyResourceNotFoundException exception in service or dao layer.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a logical error in `getAllEmployee` method. Because, if in `employeeService.findAllEmployees()` there will be no employee, then by the logic of code it should return list of Employee with size 0. So, I think your code should look like this:

```
@GetMapping(value = "employee")
public List<Employee> getAllEmployee() throws MyResourceNotFoundException {
    List<Employee> employees = employeeService.findAllEmployees();

    if (employees.size() > 0) return employees;
    else throw new MyResourceNotFoundException("Employee not Found");
}
```